# Windows is no longer updating after reset

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

After I interrupted an installation of a Service Pack 1 download for my Windows Starter, Windows is no longer updating.  I also did a system restore.

I don't know if this is part of the issue, but I have a problem with a hacker/stalker, so I'm worried about this.

Comment: have you tried updating manually? Have you checked if the update is shown installed in the add/remove programs list? If yes, try to reinstall (modify or remove and install again) the patch.

Comment: How did you interrupt the installation of the service pack? Any errors you received? Also, what do you mean by "Windows is no longer updating". Can you please share more details?

Answer (score 2):

Interrupting a service pack installation is a BIG no-no. If you did it back in the Windows XP days you may as well have formatted your C: drive.

Windows 7 has a slightly more intelligent update process but depending on how you interrupted it you could still have caused a lot of damage. I recommend you backup your user files and get an integrated Windows 7 service pack install, hence reinstalling windows with the latest service pack again.

Answer (score 1):

Download the SP1 package labeled "windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe" from the link below, it should be the last one in the list of downloads. Save the file to a folder of choice and execute it, it should install SP1 now, don't interrupt it this time.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5842